# (Azure) How do I get and compare the Timestamp date from Table storage in a logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to make a simple Azure logic app, never made one before. It's set to check a Timestamp from a table in Table Storage.

I get a result List of Entities that contains the Timestamp that I want to compare but my question is how do I compare the value of "Timestamp" with for example utcNow() that is a string?

[image: Get entities]

```
  {
    "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2020-05-07T09%3A07%3A32.8275489Z'\"",
    "Timestamp": "2020-05-07T09:07:32.8275489Z"
  },
```

[image: The error I get for now]

I just want to get the Timestamp-string out so I can compare it to the utcNow-string.

Comment: Is your question regarding how to write a query on `Timestamp` attribute?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below works ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the screenshots you provided, it seems the error happened in the "condition" to compare the timestamp. If you want to know how to compare the timestamp, you can refer to my sample below:

I initialize a variable(string) named "Timestamp" to simulate your timestamp from your table storage. In "Condition" we can use "[ticks()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks)" method to convert the timestamp(string) to ticks(number) and then compare them.

[image]

The expressions before and after the "is less than" are:

```
ticks(variables('Timestamp'))

ticks(utcNow())
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thank you for your help, my issue was more that I needed to get the Timestamp from a table and "operate on that". Didn't know how since it was saved as an object and not string or DateTime - Worked out with a filter instead